# Android emulator on VS 2015?

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator

I just installed Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3 (with Xamarin) from scratch from the 7GB ISO.
My aim is to create a blank Xamarin project and run it in an Android emulator.

But in the Start button, I can't even see the device/emulator selections.
[image]

I thought Visual Studio comes with an Android emulator.
What am I missing? How can I run it on an emulator?

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx

Comment: ah... I can't install it because I'm still on Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure with your Visual Studio version but it's an optional feature in Visual Studio Enterprise. I had to choose it specifically to install it. You can go to *Programs and Features*, choose to *change* Visual Studio 2015, then choose *Modify* and add the Android Emulator like this:

[image: This is the option you need to choose to install the Android Emulator]

Comment: I don't have that for some reason. Instead that item says "WebSocket4Net". Thanks anyway! I'll try downloading it as Sushi suggested

Comment: @Aximili ok, that might be a limitation of Visual Studio Community edition.